# ubuntu: how to check if a directory not exist or empty?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

ubuntu: how to check if a directory not exist or empty?

```
   if [not_exist "/path" || empty "/path"] then
       command1; 
   else
       command2;
   fi
```

Comment: See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-check-if-directory-empty/ + https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-linux-or-unix-shell/

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a directory or file exists using the following syntax:

```bash
# If a directory
if [[ ! -d /path/to/dir ]]
then
   echo "directory does not exist"
fi

# If a file
if [[ ! -f /path/to/file]]
then
   echo "file does not exist"
fi
```

You are able to test if a directory is empty with the following syntax:

```bash
if [[ -z "$(ls /path/to/dir)" ]]
then
   echo "Empty"
fi
```

Comment: To use `ls` that way, you also need the **-A** option.  Otherwise, if `/path/to/dir/.foo` exists, you will think the directory is empty.